# extractValue SQL retuning multiple values in the XML in the same column followed by space

Tags: mysql, xml, extract-value

I'm using MySQL database and below is the sample XML in a attributes column of the table mytable.   I used extractValue to pull the values from XML nodes and the values are returned in a single row and are separated by a space.  I want the results to be in a different rows of the same column.

The column attributes in mytable holds the below XML that I need to query upon.

```
        <Attributes>
            <Map>
               <entry key="ABC">
                  <value>
                   <List>
                      <String>12 3</String>          
                      <String>4 56</String>    
                   </List>
                 </value>
               </entry>
            </Map>
        </Attributes>
```

I used the extractValue function to pull the values from XML nodes

```
       SELECT itemno, extractValue(attributes, '/Attributes/Map/entry[1]/value/List/String') 
               as Value FROM mytable
```

The output with the above SQL is returning:

```
itemno    Value
------    -----
1         12 3  45 6

and I want it as below

itemno    Value
------    -----
1         12 3
1         45 6
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your RDBMD and its version .

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
CREATE TABLE tbl (ID INT, attributes TEXT);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
(1, '<Attributes>
    <Map>
        <entry key="ABC">
            <value>
                <List>
                    <String>12 3</String>
                    <String>4 56</String>
                </List>
            </value>
        </entry>
    </Map>
</Attributes>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID, ExtractValue(attributes,
     '/Attributes/Map/entry[1]/value/List/String[1]/text()') as tokens
FROM tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, ExtractValue(attributes,
     '/Attributes/Map/entry[1]/value/List/String[2]/text()') as tokens
FROM tbl;
```

Comment: Thank you.  The above solution works only when you have 2 nodes and you joined the results.  How to modify the above SQL if the number of nodes are dynamic ?  I may have 1,2 -- 10 or none ?